# Can "who" be used to refer to an organization that is acting on something?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I searched but couldn't find information on using "who" to state that an organization (not a person) is taking some action. I'm curious what the specific English rule is. Is it proper to use "who" in this sentence:

> The notification was sent to the Office of Investigations **who** requested an inspection of the parts in December 2019.

Comment: ...the cited usage is "acceptable", but as the linked answer points out, [***which** would've been more suitable.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/121571/126)

Comment: Can a question be closed as a duplicate when the original does not have an accepted answer?